# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image_name' cannot be null [Vich Uploader]

Tags: php, html, vichuploaderbundle

I know this question has been asked many times, but no one has answered it correctly and nothing seems to be working.

**My Error**

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO pre_order_image
>   (image_name, updatedAt, preOrder_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params
>   [null, "2018-01-17 05:24:27", 6]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'image_name' cannot be null

**My Config**

```
 prOrder_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/uploads/preOrders
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads/preOrders
            namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

**My Entity**

```
 * @var File
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="prOrder_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 */
private $imageFile;

 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PreOrder", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preOrder_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $preOrder;

private $remove;

/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
 *
 * @return PreOrderImage
 */
public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
{
    $this->imageFile = $image;

    if ($image) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getImageFile()
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set imageName
 *
 * @param string $imageName
 * @return PreOrderImage
 */
public function setImageName($imageName)
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imageName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return PreOrderImage
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Set preOrder
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\PreOrder $preOrder
 * @return PreOrderImage
 */
public function setPreOrder(\AppBundle\Entity\PreOrder $preOrder = null)
{
    $this->preOrder = $preOrder;
    $preOrder->addImage($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get preOrder
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\PreOrder
 */
public function getPreOrder()
{
    return $this->preOrder;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getRemove()
{
    return $this->remove;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $remove
 */
public function setRemove($remove)
{
    $this->remove = $remove;
}
```

**My Controller**

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // create preOrder ad object
        $preOrder = new PreOrder();
        $preOrder->setSeller($this->getUser()->getSeller())
            ->setName($request->get('preOrder_title'))
            ->setPrice($request->get('preOrder_price'))
            ->setQuantity($request->get('preOrder_quantity'))
            ->setDescription01($request->get('preOrder_description01'))
            ->setDescription02($request->get('preOrder_description02'))
            ->setDescription03($request->get('preOrder_description03'))
            ->setDescription04($request->get('preOrder_description04'))
            ->setDescription05($request->get('preOrder_description05'))
            ->setSubLocation($this->getRepository('SubLocation')->find($request->get('preOrder_sub_location')))
            ->setSubCategory($subCategory)
            ->setContactNo(empty($request->get('preOrder_contactNo')) ? $this->getUser()->getMobile() : $request->get('preOrder_contactNo'))
            ->setEmail(empty($request->get('preOrder_email')) ? $this->getUser()->getEmail() : $request->get('preOrder_email'))
            ->setDiscount(!empty($request->get('preOrder_discount')) ? $request->get('preOrder_discount') : null);

        // filter out null images
        $imageArray = array_filter($request->files->all());

        // create image objects
        foreach($imageArray as $item){
            $image = new PreOrderImage();
            $image->setImageFile($item);
            $image->setPreOrder($preOrder);
        }

        $em->persist($preOrder);
        $em->flush();
```

Comment: You never set the image name.

Comment: I can set the name manually when flushing to the data base. it will take away the error but the image wont be uploaded. Vich uploader usually takes the name automatically.

Comment: tanx for the edits guys !!